# @WebMvcTest mapperscan conflict

Tags: spring-boot

My project used `spring-boot` (1.4.0.release) and `mybatis-spring-boot-starter`. When I try to have some test code for controller, I always get a exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
at org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(SqlSessionDaoSupport.java:75)
at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:74)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 42 more`
```

But when I comment `@MapperScan("com.toby.mapper")`, it runs very well.
Here is my example class:

```html
@MapperScan("com.toby.mapper")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppConfig.class)
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.toby.configuration,com.toby.web.controller,com.toby.service,com.toby.dao")
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(Example.class).run(args);
        SpringApplication application=new SpringApplication(Example.class);
        application.addInitializers(new PropertyPasswordDecodingContextInitializer());
        application.run(args);
    }

}
```

Here is my test code:

```html
package com.toby.web.controller;

import com.toby.common.config.AppConfig;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

/**
 * Created by Toby on 2016/8/10.
 */
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = MyRestController.class)
public class MyRestControllerTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private AppConfig appConfig;

    @Test
    public void testHome() throws Exception {
        /*this.mvc.perform(get("/users").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string("Honda Civic"));*/
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the dependencies of `MyRestController`?  Spring Boot is only going to register that class as a bean so anything that you'd rely on in the controller needs to be either provided or mocked.

Comment: MyRestController  just a very simple demo;     only depend on @Autowired  private AppConfig appConfig;   and also have another controller depend on database related resources

Comment: The problem is that i have specify @WebMvcTest(value = MyRestController.class) in test code.  why another controller was effected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you've updated the description or I didn't read it properly the first time. `@MapperScan` is a mybatis specific annotation that triggers something but is missing some guard of some sort.

We had the same problem in boot actually. Let's say you put `@EnableCaching` on your main app. Because slicing disables *all auto-configurations* but a list of specific ones, the cache auto-configuration would not kick in and you'll get an exception because the `CacheManager` isn't found. To fix that issue, we've started to create some annotation to easily enable those. If you look at `WebMbcTest` you'll see it's annotated with `AutoConfigureCache` that's going to provide a dummy no-op cache manager unless specified otherwise.

Your problem is that the mybatis support is a third party integration and there isn't any support for that. Some solutions:

- Change `@WebMbvcTest` to provide the class of another configuration class, effectivly disabling the use of your main spring boot app. Of course that class shouldn't define the `@MapperScan` annotation
- Move the `MapperScan` (and anything that's not required with slicing) to another `Configuration` class. It could be a class in the same package as your app. Slicing won't scan those by default so you'll be fine. It's by far the easiest
- Create an issue in the mybatis support so that they improve the auto-configuration to back-off (prevent this exception). I am not sure that's possible actually

Long story short, since `@MapperScan` is a way to tell mybatis to scan your entities, maybe you shouldn't add it on your main boot app if you use slicing. Because your `@WebMbcTest` doesn't want to use that obviously.